# What resources would be needed to play a 2e Dragonlance campaign?

Tags: adnd-2e, books, dragonlance

I've started playing D&D again (5e). It inspired me to look at my old gaming books and I got nostalgic for AD&D 2e. I started to reread the PHB and remembered the fun I had with Dragonlance. So, that lead me to research what resources would be needed to play a 2e Dragonlance campaign.

What I've come up with is:

- PHB & DMG 2e
- Monstrous Compendium v1 and 4
- Dragonlance Classics: 15th Anniversary Edition

Am I correct in my reading the the Classics book contains all the DL modules converted to 2e?  Should I also get the AD&D Dragonlance Adventures?  What other resources do I need to run these adventures?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Nothing else is needed.

For details about what *Dragonlance Classics: 15th Anniversary Edition* contains (and what is partially missing) you can read Shannon Applecline's detailed product history, [available on the DM's Guild](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/219096/Dragonlance-Classics-15th-Anniversary-Edition-2e-SAGA). Quoting:

> The 15th Anniversary book is a wholescale rewrite of the original Dragonlance Chronicles adventures from the ground up.

To run the game, what you need is quoted in the book itself (page 6, Introduction chapter):

> If you wish to roleplay the adventure, you need not only be familiar with at least one set of roleplaying game rules, but you should possess previous knowledge of the DRAGONLANCE® world to get the fullest benefit from this adventure. To familiarize yourself with a set of game rules, you can pick up ... the Player’s Handbook and DUNGEON MASTER® Guide.

So if you are already familiar with the setting, you should be able play with your list of books. One improvement would be to replace *Monstrous Compendium Volume 1* with the more comprehensive *Monstrous Manual*. The "Monster Statistics Chart" in DC:15thAE refers to page numbers directly from the MM. For example, you will not find the statistics for banshee in the compendium but they are available in the MM.

Answer (score 4):

### Not much more!

The books you gathered should be able to do the job alone, but your players may need the [Player's Guide to the Dragonlance Campaign](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/16964/PG1-Players-Guide-to-the-Dragonlance-Campaign-2e) if they are unfamiliar with the Dragonlance setting.

The [Monstrous Manual](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/16865/Monstrous-Manual-2e) can be also be used in place of the Monstrous Compendiums 1 and 4, as it has both compendiums and all the others released for 2E.

And, as [ZwiQ pointed on his answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/148433/47052), the DMsGuild page of the [Dragonlance Classics: 15th Anniversary Edition](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/219096/Dragonlance-Classics-15th-Anniversary-Edition-2e-SAGA) has a very detailed description of the product.